# The correct way to use TypeScript declarations (*.d.ts) and interfaces?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

It seems that there are two ways of using interfaces in TypeScript: I can define them in ordinary .ts files and import them, or I can define them in .d.ts files and have the compiler discover them automatically from node_modules/@types or by adding relevant paths to typeRoots in tsconfig.json, and they become "magically" available everywhere.

Currently I have two projects: a client (React) and a server (Express), both written in TypeScript. I have certain interfaces that I use in both projects, and in order to avoid dependencies between the projects, I extracted the common interfaces to a separate project into declaration files. Then I added the project as a dev dependency this way:

```
"@types/my-definitions": "git+ssh://git@github.com/myaccount/my-definitions.git"
```

This way TypeScript compiler automatically finds the interfaces from node_modules/@types, and I don't have to import the interfaces.

My question is, is this a good practice, or should I instead have the interfaces inside ordinary .ts files, import the project as ordinary dependency and explicitly import the interfaces that I'm using? What are the pros and cons of each approaches?

Answer (score 0):

`.d.ts` files are generated as the output of a typescript project (along with the compiled JS) based on your `.ts` files.

Typically those are brought in through imports, not by being magically discovered because they are in a specially named folder.

The time where you do want to put `.d.ts` in that magical folder so they are available to all code is when you are using environment JS globals defined by DOM/BOM/NodeJS. You don't need to explicitly import them, they are just always available (like they would be in JavaScript)

However, when dealing with an actual library (that outputs JavaScript code). You should just import the library through package.json and configure TypeScript to resolve modules by looking into node_modules.

**Example**

Calling `document.createElement()` returns an `HTMLElement`. By adding environment definitions, you don't have to import a `document` object.

However, suppose you are using Angular, when you want to use an angular class, you do have to explicitly import it

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core"
```

TypeScript will know to look for the `ts` files in `node_modules/@angular/core`. It could be a raw `.ts` but those are not usually packaged as the output of a TypeScript project, usually you only get the compiled JS and the `.d.ts` files.

**Summary**

You should treat your reusable code as a third-party library like angular and import it the same way. Don't magically add those definitions to the environment (we have enough globals as is)